# Extracting data from XML response in VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, ebay-api

I am trying to extract nodes from eBay API XML response into single order lines

```
 Sub GetSellerTransactions() 
 Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
 URL = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll"
 objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME", "________"
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME", "________"
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME", "________"
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "GetSellerTransactions"
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-SITEID", "0"
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-Encoding", "XML"
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL", "967"

 objHTTP.send (body)

 Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
 objXML.LoadXML (objHTTP.ResponseText)

 Dim xItemList As IXMLDOMNodeList
 Set xItemList = objXML.SelectNodes("//Item")

 Row = 1

 Dim xItem As IXMLDOMNode
 Dim copy As Worksheet

 For Each xItem In xItemList
     Cells(Row, 1) = xItem.SelectNodes("//Buyer/UserID").Item(0).Text
     Cells(Row, 2) = xItem.SelectNodes("//Buyer/Name").Item(0).Text
     Cells(Row, 3) = xItem.SelectNodes("///Buyer/Phone").Item(0).Text
     Cells(Row, 4) = xItem.SelectNodes("//Buyer/Email").Item(0).Text
     Row = Row + 1
 Next

 Set objHTTP = Nothing
 Set objXML = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code gives me the following output:[image: output]

The data is completely mixed up, for example

- "johnk" doesn't have an Address 2, but the code gave it "marilyn43's"
  value
- "macchi" doesn't have an email, and the code gave it "marilyn43's"
  value

what is wrong? Maybe I need pointers in the `for` loop? Or is this `for` loop completely wrong?

Comment: Hard to say what the issue is without seeing the XML you're trying to parse

Comment: You probably don't want to use `//` in your xpath expressions in the loop, since that will match all items in the document, not just those in `xItem`.  See:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: here's the XML I'm trying to parse http://wikisend.com/download/339596/API.xhtml

Comment: hmm I removed the // but got the run-time '91' error (Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: There are no `buyer` elements nested inside `item`, so it's not clear what you're attempting with your code.

Comment: hmm, its the only value that worked with the loop (I tried to replace with "order" and "orderarray" but that didn't work)

Comment: So what exactly are you wanting to extract?

Comment: I simply would like to extract each order in the XML and then paste in single order lines; I just need these values: BuyerUserID, Name, Phone, Email, Street1, Street2, CityName, StateOrProvince, PostalCode, CountryName, Title, ItemID, TransactionID

Comment: Then use `Set xItemList = objXML.SelectNodes("//Order")` and work from there.

Comment: yes it does make more sense, though I'm still having some trouble with extracting the right values from each instance of the For loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TimWilliams suggests, you need to accurately traverse your XML as those needed values are nested in different areas all descendants of `<Order>`. Only *Title* and *ItemID* are children of `<Item>`.

Consider the following adjustment using XPath's `descendant` and be sure to set a prefix to the undeclared namespace. Also, try using `SelectSingleNode()` as you are extracting one value per item:

```vb
Sub GetSellerTransactions() 
On Error Goto ErrHandle
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    URL = "https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME", "________"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME", "________"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME", "________"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME", "GetSellerTransactions"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-SITEID", "0"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-Encoding", "XML"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL", "967"

    objHTTP.send (body)

    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    objXML.async = False
    objXML.LoadXML (objHTTP.ResponseText)

    XmlNamespaces = "xmlns:doc='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'"
    objXML.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", XmlNamespaces
    objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

    Dim xItemList As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Set xItemList = objXML.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//doc:Transaction")

    Row = 5

    Dim xItem As IXMLDOMNode

    For Each xItem In xItemList
        Cells(Row, 1) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::doc:Order/doc:BuyerUserID").Text
        Cells(Row, 2) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::doc:Order/descendant::doc:ShipToAddress[1]/doc:Name").Text
        Cells(Row, 3) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::doc:Order/descendant::doc:ShipToAddress[1]/doc:Phone").Text
        Cells(Row, 4) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::doc:Order/descendant::doc:Buyer/doc:Email").Text
        Cells(Row, 5) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::doc:Order/descendant::doc:ShipToAddress/doc:Street1").Text
        Cells(Row, 6) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::doc:Order/descendant::doc:ShipToAddress/doc:Street2").Text
        Cells(Row, 7) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::doc:Order/descendant::doc:ShipToAddress/doc:StateOrProvince").Text
        Cells(Row, 8) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::doc:Order/descendant::doc:ShipToAddress/doc:PostalCode").Text
        Cells(Row, 9) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("ancestor::doc:Order/descendant::doc:ShipToAddress/doc:CountryName").Text
        Cells(Row, 10) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("descendant::doc:Item/doc:ItemID").Text
        Cells(Row, 11) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("descendant::doc:Item/doc:Title").Text
        Cells(Row, 12) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("doc:TransactionID").Text
        Cells(Row, 13) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("descendant::doc:NameValueList[1]/doc:Name").Text
        Cells(Row, 14) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("descendant::doc:NameValueList[position()=1]/doc:Value").Text
        Cells(Row, 15) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("descendant::doc:NameValueList[2]/doc:Name").Text
        Cells(Row, 16) = xItem.SelectSingleNode("descendant::doc:NameValueList[position()=2]/doc:Value").Text
        Row = Row + 1
    Next xItem

    Set objHTTP = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    ' MISSING NODE ERROR
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        Resume Next
    ' ALL OTHER ERRORS
    Else:
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: here's the output Im getting: https://s16.postimg.io/7y4u58p9x/output.png

Comment: @idan - Don't use `//` in front of your XPath's within the loop: if you use `//` then it won't operate in the correct context: you need to be searching within `xItem`, not within the whole document. See the page I linked earlier: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @idan See update using XPath's `descendant` to properly retrieve the nodes at each corresponding `<Order>`. Notice too, I declare a prefix *doc* due to undeclared namespace in xml doc.

Comment: @ TimWilliams @ Parfait that worked! one more thing, how do I do if I want it to skip the empty nodes? (e.g. if street2 = "" then skip to StateOrProvince) to prevent the run-time error 91 from popping up

Comment: Use `If...Then` on returned xpath text value like any other VBA variable inside loop. And why do you want to skip? Are you not returning a tabular output. Then, leave missing values blank in column. Do note, error will popup if node does not exist.

Comment: https://s15.postimg.io/v3is39x6j/Untitled1.png hmm I tried this but it results in runtime error 91; yes some orders are occasionally missing certain values (like street2 or email) so these missing values need be left blank in the columns; how do I get around it?

Comment: Then use error handling, conditioned on error 91: `Resume Next` for missing nodes which will continue on leaving blanks. See update of full adjusted macro.

Comment: It worked perfectly! one thing I'm a little confused about, either the XML is missing data or I'm using the wrong ebay call (they have two types of calls for retrieving orders: GetSellerTransactions or GetOrders - I'm using the latter) here's the problem: https://s10.postimg.org/bfk318eax/20160823194631.png

Comment: this explains better https://s10.postimg.org/a9ylk10g9/20160823200315.png

Comment: Great! Please accept solution if it worked. And there is no way I can check that missing data without seeing actual XML. Do a search on that buyer and see if it falls under two `<Order>` tags.

Comment: Ok :) I never thought I'd find a solution here so quickly by the way

Comment: hmm, how do I export the XML response to an XML file? I would like to browse through the nodes (http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/build-test/test-tool/?api=trading&call=GetOrders&variation=xml&env=production this is the api doc btw if it helps) I think that buyer's Order has two Transactions (as childs of Order) but I'd like to see the XML output to be sure

Comment: Any where after `objXML.LoadXML objHTTP.ResponseText`, go ahead and save the document `objXML.Save "C:\Path\To\XML.xml"`.

Comment: ok got it! here's the actual output: https://s9.postimg.org/heydgemkf/OUTPU2.jpg you're right, that buyer had two separate Transactions, but they were included inside their Order tag; so I changed ("//doc:Order") to ("//doc:Transaction") but then it didn't pull the ShippingAddress and BuyerUserID (which are included in Order, but not in Transaction) how do I go from here?

Comment: image: http://oi64.tinypic.com/35damok.jpg I got the exact output I wanted, just the ShippingAddress values and BuyerUserID are blank in the columns (because they aren't included in Transaction)

Comment: See update. You will have to use `ancestor::*` to back up to `<Order>` level if iterating on each transaction: `//doc:Transaction`.

Comment: one thing about the variations, how do I pull multiple Names and Values from the Variation? (some variations have multiple Names, like Size and Color; and some Variations have just one Name, like just Size) xml https://s13.postimg.org/ymtn8u7t3/20160825014708.png; code https://s10.postimg.org/47pcs07ll/code.png; output https://s14.postimg.io/fb0z5kjz5/var_output.png

Comment: I polished the code to my needs (even put it in a nice activex button haha) and it all works like a charm, can't thank you enough! last thing I need to resolve is the multiple variation specifics and it's all done :)

Comment: Use node indexing or xpath's [position()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) function: `doc:NameValueList[1]` or `doc:NameValueList[position()=1]`. See update using either. If only you had enough pts. could upvote the answer! Glad I could help.

Comment: https://s9.postimg.org/4h117kogf/Untitled.jpg works exactly the way I wanted; thanks so much for your time with me on this, wish I had enough rep to upvote! I'm sure other people who might across this question will find your answer as helpful as it was for me! thanks a lot!

Comment: Do note, you do not need `position()` for items after the first, `doc:NameValueList[2]`, `doc:NameValueList[3]`, ... also works. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: well noted, that's just fine! I got it all working in the right order, also learned a lot from the process & solution! thanks a lot :)